# Loading Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**Goal**: I would like to include all of a customers medical conditions as an array in the result of a customer.

for:

```
cust = Customer.includes(:conditions).find(1)
```

expected result:

```
#<Customer id: 1, first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", conditions [...]>
```

actual result:

```
#<Customer id: 1, first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe">
```

**code**:

I have 2 classes and a 3rd join class (ConditionsCustomer).

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :conditions_customers
    has_many :conditions, through: :conditions_customers
end

#join table. Contains 2 foreign_keys (customer_id, condition_id)
class ConditionsCustomer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :condition
end

class Condition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conditions_customers
  has_many :customers, through: :conditions_customers
end
```

What's interesting is that I see 3 select queries getting fired (customer, join table and medical conditions table) so I know the includes is somewhat working but unfortunately customer returns without the medical conditions.

I've also tried using a join but I get an array of same customer over and over again.

Is there an easy way to do this with ActiveRecord? I would prefer not having to merge the record manually.

Comment: `Customer.eager_load(:conditions).find(1)`.  This will load the joined tables in the same query. Unlike `.joins` this uses a left outer join so rows with no matches are also returned. https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Comment: You should also be aware that the associated records are not included in the output from `.inspect`. You will get `#<Customer id: 1, first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe">` no matter if the association is loaded or not.
Instead you need to call `Customer.eager_load(:conditions).find(1).conditions.inspect` if you want to debug it.

Comment: Thanks, but in my controller I do: `cust = Customer.eager_load(:conditions).find(params[:id])` and then `render json: cust and return`. Still no medical conditions in the result .. as verified by my postman tool

Comment: @JohnMarsh you rennder the `cust` as json ... but where to you call `.conditions`?

Comment: `as_json` does not include associations by default. You have to explicitly tell it to include the association. `render json: cust, include: [:conditions]`

Comment: Ahh that's where the magic happens. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible via active record, as json offers some cool possibilities :

```
render json: customers,
       include: {
         conditions: {
           only: [:attr1, :attr2], # filter returned fields
           methods: [:meth1, :meth2] # if you need model methods
         },
         another_joined_model: {
             except: [:password] # to exclude specific fields
         }
       }
```